# Write speed of gluster volume reduced over time

Tags: glusterfs

I have a gluster volume with the following configuration.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Number of Bricks: 9
Transport-type: tcp

Hot Tier :

Hot Tier Type : Replicate

Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3

Cold Tier:

Cold Tier Type : Distributed-Replicate

Number of Bricks: 2 x 3 = 6

performance.flush-behind: on

performance.cache-max-file-size: 128MB

performance.cache-size: 25GB

diagnostics.count-fop-hits: off

diagnostics.latency-measurement: off

cluster.tier-mode: cache

features.ctr-enabled: on

transport.address-family: inet

nfs.disable: on

performance.client-io-threads: off

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Without write cache, bricks in hot tier got around 1.5 GB/s write speed and bricks in cold tier got 700 MB/s. However, I am getting only around 35 MB/s write speed in gluster volume mounted in glusterfs.

I checked and confirmed that I can get network throughput as much as 1.4 Gbits/sec.

The volume had around 175 MB/s write speed initially, however, speed reduced as more data stored in the volume. I also implemented a second volume with similar configuration, and I am getting write speed around 175 MB/s again.

Could someone please advise on what could be done to improve write speed.

Is NFS Ganesha a solution to improve write speed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your underlying bricks made of? It's generally advised that they be thin LVM + XFS. I've had this exact issue when using BTRFS as bricks - the data areas scattered to the winds on each drive.

Comment: I got XFS file system in all bricks. 

I am not using LVM. 

Bricks in cold tier are normal hard disks

Bricks in hot tier are SSDs